# link to another HTML page in an offline theme design

Tags: html

I made an index.html and wrote this:
`<a href="/contact.html/">Contact</a>`

Ok, it doesn't work, it refers to `file:///contact.html` as I want to refer:

`file:///E:/THEME/contact.html`

Note. *The contact.html is in the same root.*

*I should note that I haven't access to `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1`*

Comment: Didn't understood a bit.

Comment: Just make it `contact.html`.

Comment: Try removing the prefix slash in the contact link `<a href="contact.html">Contact</a>`

Comment: @Mr.Alien It means my links wont work, I want my navigation links, for example contact link, refer to contact.html, but when I click it, nothing heppen.

Comment: It starts here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1808 and then it has been updated to here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the index.html and contact.html are in the same folder, then get rid of both the slashes in the value for the HREF attribute.

Comment: And how to link to the home page? without the use of href="index.html", I use href="/", but it refer to file:///

Comment: @Farzad It seems you don't have a slightest idea how paths for directories work. You may search and learn it first since this is really common (and basic) knowledge.

Comment: @HamZa I'm just a bit "confused" in working offline. I use "/" for homepage, I know the root is file:// not my domain name, ok, so should I write "/" and don't care that I'm coding offline?

Comment: if you use the file name (such as href="contact.html" or href="index.html") you are safe both offline AND online  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<a href="contact.html">contact</a>
```

or

```
<a href="./contact.html">contact</a>
```

where `./` means "this folder".
This link

```
<a href="./">home</a>
```

will go to `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove first '/' Like this:-

```
<a href="contact.html/">Contact</a>
```

Comment: `contact.html` is not a directory, if you get what I mean.

Comment: I think you getting problem when you open 'index.html' with double click...and than you saw path in address bar like 'file://'...